# How do I access the "Save Thumbnail" feature of Excel through Interop?

Tags: c#, vsto

I'm working on an Excel add-in using C# and .NET 4.0.  In Excel there's a feature in the Save-As dialog for saving a preview thumbnail along with the document.  How can I access this feature in code? Also, how do I access the preview image (I think it's a bitmap) once it has been saved?

Currently my Excel add-in makes a copy of the document as follows:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs("tempwbcopy");
```

It then copies the document to a server and erases the temp file.  Basically I'd like to also make the thumbail image, post it to the server, and erase the temp file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to access the Save Thumbnail feature programatically, but if you have a Excel file with a thumbnail and want to extract the image you could use the following code (using the OpenXml 2.0 API):

```
Private Sub ExtractThumbnailAsPng(ByVal pathToExcelFile As String, ByVal outputPath As String)

    Dim thumbnailPart As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.ThumbnailPart

    Using excelFile As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(pathToExcelFile, True)
        thumbnailPart = excelFile.ThumbnailPart
        If thumbnailPart IsNot Nothing Then
            Using thumbnailStream As Stream = thumbnailPart.GetStream(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
                Dim thumbBitmap As New Bitmap(thumbnailStream)
                thumbBitmap.Save(outputPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            End Using
        End If
    End Using

End Sub
```

Since this isn't Excel automation you could do this server side as well.